# Post on facebook using ImpactWorks.FBGraph in asp.net mvc c# gives error the remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

i have implement functionality of POST in facebook using graph API using ImpactWorks.FBGraph.dll in my Asp.net MVC project.  in last when it calls function facebook.PostToWall() then gives error remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

my code below

```
public Facebook FacebookAuth()
        {
            //Setting up the facebook object
            Facebook facebook = new ImpactWorks.FBGraph.Connector.Facebook();


            facebook.AppID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            facebook.Secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            facebook.CallBackURL = "http://localhost/Retail_MVC/Facebook/Success";

            //Setting up the permissions
            List<FBPermissions> permissions = new List<FBPermissions>() {
                FBPermissions.user_about_me, // to read about me               
                FBPermissions.user_events,
                FBPermissions.user_status,
                FBPermissions.read_stream,
                FBPermissions.friends_events,
                FBPermissions.publish_stream,
            };

            //Pass the permissions object to facebook instance
            facebook.Permissions = permissions;
            return facebook;
        }
```

and my return URL function is below, before it i have done authentication functionality using authLink

```
public ActionResult Success()
        {
                Facebook facebook = auth.FacebookAuth();
 string Code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] = Code;
                facebook.GetAccessToken(Session["facebookQueryStringValue"].ToString());
                FBUser currentUser = facebook.GetLoggedInUserInfo();
                IFeedPost FBpost = new FeedPost();

                    FBpost.Message = "Hello, whats up"
                    facebook.PostToWall(currentUser.id.GetValueOrDefault(), FBpost);

            return View();
        }
```

when calling last function PostToWall() then  its gives error
"the remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

please give me proper solution to solve this.